# When changing schemas must I update the receive pipeline component?

Tags: biztalk

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline:   Reason: No
>   Disassemble stage components can recognize the data.

I had some sort of automate generated schema (.xsd) and needed to add two columns and added those manually.

Then I updated the dll:s: schema, map and pipeline.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have increased the version number on your Schemas assembly, or changed the XML#NS root of your schema, then you will need to update your pipeline. Also, try deleting the generated .cs files, rebuild all from scratch, and remember to restart your host process(es).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your testing your pipeline with some test message using a FILE adapter (what I typically do!).

So, in addition to nonnb's suggestions, ensure that the message you are sending through the receive pipeline also has these two new columns - otherwise the validation of the incoming message will fail (as the schema you've set in the pipeline isn't conformed to by the message)

HTH